# Will EWS become obsolete in the near future?

Tags: exchange

A colleague of mine claims that EWS is "legacy" and that we should use other ways of programming for Exchange.  I agree that asmx services are "legacy" but I have found no indication that Microsoft intends to give up on EWS with the improvements to EWS in Exchange 2010 and the publication of the EWS Managed API.

Is it safe to continue using EWS?

Comment: Can your colleague cite an official source? I find it hard to believe something relatively new is being considered legacy. Things aren't legacy unless they're replaced by something, and off the top of my head I can't think of anything.

Comment: @Ben Pilbrow: I feel the same way that you do and he has not been able to come up with any liable source.

Comment: The way MS has been pushing EWS, I think it might be the long term replacement for MAPI.